# Input value not returned in Switch within canvas

Tags: javascript

Still new to programming and currently, I am trying to create a game (questions and answers by slecting a number from the keyboard), however for some reason the JS is not waiting for my form submit in order to process it properly.

Here is some of the code that I have in short:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>

Choose between 1 - 4: <input type="text" id="fname">
<button>Submit</button>


<script>
var continueAnimating=true;    

function draw() {

if(!continueAnimating){return;}



 if (question == 0) {

var pop = 7;                                       // can be any number
var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*pop) + 1;      // Generate random number

if (rand1 <= 3) {
 questionOne();
 continueAnimating=false;  // using this to stop the loop between questions

 var bbb = document.getElementById("fname").value; //getting value from input form



    switch (parseInt(bbb)) {
      case 1: 
      question = question++;
      corrAnswer();
      break;
      case 2: wrongAnswer(); break;
      case 3: wrongAnswer(); break;
      case 4: wrongAnswer(); break;
      default: alert('Choose 1,2,3 or 4 numbers from the keyboard!');
        }


} else if(rand1 > 3) {

 questionTwo();
continueAnimating=false;

   var bbb = document.getElementById("fname").value;



    switch (parseInt(bbb)) {
      case 1: wrongAnswer(); break;
      case 2: wrongAnswer(); break;
      case 3: 
      question == question++;
      corrAnswer();
      break;
      case 4: wrongAnswer(); break;
      default: alert('Choose 1,2,3 or 4 numbers from the keyboard!');
        }

}
}



requestAnimationFrame(draw);                  // within the DRAW () function ***
}

setInterval(draw, 10);        // 10 milisec to draw next frame

</script>
```

As you can see there are some functions that I have declared already but the main point is that once I load this, it simply gives me the message from :

```
  default: alert('Choose 1,2,3 or 4 numbers from the keyboard!');
    }
```

Instead of actually taking the 1,2,3 or 4 value from the form and then continue executing. The simple game is not completed of course, but any help with that will be much appreciated to make it work  with the input values.

Learning something new everyday (if possible in Javascript only would be much appreciated). Not sure if I have the perfect approach in that situation but hopefully there is a way to do it that way.

Comment: What  question == question++; this is assignment or comparison?

Comment: should not have included that , just skip it :D It is simply counting the questions var that I have in there to change the question later on. Sry about that one. Just ignore it.